# Sum of a column in SQLITE produces different results from Sum in R of the same column

Tags: r, csv, sqlite

Goal: move a csv file into an sqlite database passing through R (I can't avoid passing through R) and perform some queries on the Sqlite database from R.

Problem: When I perform a simple query on the sqlite database (sum of a column) and I do the same calculation in R by summing the column of the data frame (same data as in the sqlite database) I get two completely different results.

So far, I don't know which one I should trust. Notice that I can't open the csv file in excel to check manually since the file is very large.

I have already tried to change the type of the column when moving the csv file into the sqlite database. So far, I have tried: Integer, numeric, double, real.

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "data/table.sqlite")


q1 <- "
SELECT
sum(table.values)
FROM
table;
"

t1 <- dbGetQuery(con, q1)
t1


# Sum the same column from the data frame within R
s1 <- sum(table$values)
```

In this case I compare t1 (the sum of the "values" column with SQLite) with sq (the sum of the "values" column with R) and they don't match. The error is extremely big. Not only decimals... I get a difference of millions... (I am working on a very big file).

I also checked whether the column of my dataframe in R i equal to the column in the SQLite database and they are!

```
q2 <- "
SELECT
table.values
FROM
table;
"
t2 <- dbGetQuery(con, q2)
t2

sum(t2$values == table$values)
```

The last row of code gives me 3000000 which mean that all the elements are equal since both my dataframe and sqlite database have 3000000 rows.

I simply would like to know how can I get the same result both from the R and Sqlite database.

Am I missing something about the types of the values inside the Sqlite database?

Operating system: Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
SQLite 3

Thank you in advance for your super precious help!

Comment: When I run the query q2 I get all the values of "values" column inside the sqlite databases stored into t2 (a simple data frame in R). Therefore when I run this sum(t2$values == table$values) I check whether the values retrieved with the query q2 are the same as the ones inside the data frame "table" in the column "values". Remember that "table" iis the equivalent dataframe that I have also in form of SQLite called "table".

Comment: Which results do you get using the two different methods? Is the dataset available somewhere? To me this sounds like a numeric overflow somewhere, but with so little information available it's hard to say where.